# Tab Bar Application with Navigation Controllers in the tabs. Crosslinking from views

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

This is my first iPhone project and all has been going very well but I've run into a small snag that I can't seem to find a good solution for.  Thanks in advance to everyone who takes their time to help me out.

I have a very straight forward Tab Bar application with a few tabs.  Each tab defines a subsection that is controlled with a Navigation Bar.  The client now wants to place a button in one of the views of the subsection that "deep links" into a view of a different section ( different tab).

To Illustrate:

```
Root
  - Tab 1 (Bedrock)
     - Navigation Controller
        - Fred View
        - Wilma View
        - Betty View
        - Barney View
   - Tab 2 (Mystery Machine)
     - NC
        - Scooby View
        - Shaggy View
        - Daphnie View
        ...
```

The client would like a button in 'Barney View' that opens up 'Shaggy View'

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the `selectedViewController` or `selectedIndex` property of the UITabBarController to switch tabs, and the `viewControllers` property of the UINavigationController to set the view stack.